# Python pygame blit the same image multiple times

Tags: python, pygame, surface, blit, imagesloaded

Why cant my program blit the same image that it loaded multiple times?

```
Imagea = pygame.image.load('imagea.png')
Imageb = pygame.image.load('imageb.png')
```

Inside gameloop

```
deck = abaa
for i in deck:
     for position in positions:
      if(i) == deck[0]:
           if(i == a):
           gamedisplay.blit(imagea, positions[0])
           elif(i == b):
           gamedisplay.blit(imageb, positions[0])
      if(i) == deck[1]:
           if(i == a):
           gamedisplay.blit(imagea, positions[1])
           elif(i == b):
           gamedisplay.blit(imageb, positions[1])
      if(i) == deck[2]:
           if(i == a):
           gamedisplay.blit(imagea, positions[2])
           elif(i == b):
           gamedisplay.blit(imageb, positions[2])
      if(i) == deck[3]:
           if(i == a):
           gamedisplay.blit(imagea, positions[3])
           elif(i == b):
           gamedisplay.blit(imageb, positions[3])
```

What seems to occur is only deck 0 and deck 1 show imagea and imageb. However, deck 2 and 3 does not show up at `position[2]` or `position[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

`deck` is a list and `i` is an element of the list. It is not necessary to evaluated if is an element of the list, of course it is. This evaluation is the issue.
Note, if `i` is multiple times in `deck` (e.g. at index 0 and 2), then `if i == deck[2]:` is never evaluated, because `if i == deck[o]:` is evaluated `True` first.

In the following, I assume that `deck` and `position` have the same number of elements.

Either use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to traverse `deck` and get a tuple contaning the index of the element and the element itself:

```py
for i, d in enumerate(deck):
    p = positions[i]
    if d == a:
       gamedisplay.blit(imagea, p)
    elif d == b:
       gamedisplay.blit(imageb, p)
```

Or use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to traverse `deck` and `positions` simultaneously:

```py
for d, p in zip(deck, positions):
    if d == a:
       gamedisplay.blit(imagea, p)
    elif d == b:
       gamedisplay.blit(imageb, p)
```